# C# Help: Sorting a List of Objects in C#

Tags: c#, sorting, class

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Sort objects using predefined list of sorted values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652337/sort-objects-using-predefined-list-of-sorted-values)
>   [C# Help: Sorting a List of Objects in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925471/c-help-sorting-a-list-of-objects-in-c)
>
> ### Double Post
>
> [Sorting a List of objects in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925471/c-help-sorting-a-list-of-objects-in-c/925477#925477)

```
public class CarSpecs
{

    public CarSpecs()
    {
    }

    private String _CarName;
    public String CarName
    {
        get { return _CarName; }
        set { _CarName = value; }
    }



    private String _CarMaker;
    public String CarMaker
    {
       get { return _CarMaker;}
       set { _CarMaker = value; }
    }


    private DateTime _CreationDate;
    public DateTime CreationDate
    {
        get { return _CreationDate; }
        set { _CreationDate = value; }
    }
}
```

This is a list and I am trying to figure out an efficient way to sort this list         `List<CarSpecs> CarList`, containing 6(or any integer amount) Cars, by the Car Make Date. I was going to do Bubble sort, but  will that work?  Any Help?

Thanks

Comment: Double post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/925471/c-help-sorting-a-list-of-objects-in-c/925477#925477

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/925471/c-help-sorting-a-list-of-objects-in-c

Answer (score 42):

```
CarList = CarList.OrderBy( x => x.CreationDate ).ToList();
```

Comment: Coehoom what is x?
is it lambda? how to define it?

Comment: @AdityaPatil x is a placeholder for individual items in the CarList sequence. `x => x.CreationDate` is an expression that tells the `OrderBy()` function what criteria to use for sorting the items. It means to sort by the CreationDate property of each item.

Comment: its technically called Lambda Expression right?

Answer (score 5):

First, using the shorthand syntax introduced in .Net 3.5, you could make this class definition a lot shorter:

```
public class CarSpecs
{
    public CarSpecs() { }

    public String CarName { get; set;
    public String CarMaker { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
}
```

This will compile into the exact same class as the one you have above.

Secondly, you can easily sort them using Lambda expressions or LINQ:

```
var linq = (from CarSpecs c in CarList
            orderby c.CreationDate ascending
            select c) as List<CarList>;

var lambda = CarList.OrderBy(c => c.CreationDate).ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't write your own sorting algorithm. .NET has an [`Array.Sort()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.sort.aspx) method specifically for things such as this.

Since you have a custom object, you need to define how to compare 2 objects so the sorting algorithm knows how to sort them. You can do this 1 of 2 ways:

1. Make your `CarSpecs` class implement the [`IComparable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx) interface
2. Create a class that implements [`IComparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icomparer.aspx) and pass that in as a parameter to `Array.Sort()` along with your array.

Answer (score 0):

There are already existing sorting algorithms in the BCL - Array.Sort() and List.Sort(). Implement an IComparer class that determines the sort order using the CreationDate, then put all the objects into an array or list and call the appropriate Sort() method