# Sort list containing custom type on new add

Tags: c#, list, sorting, types

So I have a custom type `Foo`:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Description {get;set;}
    public int Order {get;set;} //not unique - just some integer
    public DateTime Date {get;set;}
}
```

and a list containing this `Foo`s (see what I did there?):

```
public class FooTops : List<Foo>
{
    public string Description {get; set;}
    public DateTime Date {get; set}

    public void AddCustom(Foo foo)
    {
        if (this.Count == 0)
        {
            this.Description = foo.Description;
            this.Date = foo.Date;
        }
        else
        {
            if (foo.Order == 1)
            {
                this.Date = foo.Date;
            }
        }
        this.Add(foo);
    }
}
```

I now want to convert this list to a `SortedList`, but that list cannot take my custom type `Foo`.

How do I sort my list by `Foo.Order`? Basically I want to have many `FooTops` containing `Foo`s sorted by their `Foo.Order`.

I read about [using delegates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163922/sort-a-custom-class-list) to sort lists but they always do that *afterwards* and not "on each item added". Could I also sort my list afterwards?

---

**Solution:**

I just made the list a `SortedList<int,Foo>`. The TKey is the `Foo.Order`. Of course this key is not unique, so before the `this.Add(foo);´ line I just generate a unique key myself:

```
private in CheckForUniqueOrder(int p)
{
    if (this.ContainsKey(p))
    {
        p = p +1;
        p = CheckForUniqueOrder(p); //love recursion...
    }
    return p;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with SortedList<Key(Order),Value(Foo)>?

Comment: Can't you use a simple OrderBy method?

See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/925571/c-sharp-help-sorting-a-list-of-objects-in-c-sharp

Comment: @Bond I'm guessing that Order isn't unique

Comment: Order isn't unique - just some integer the user assigns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [SortedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.aspx) and use `Foo.Order` as key for the list.

Comment: I went with your approach, making the key unique myself (I edited the solution in the question).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to `sort` list on Add. The best would be to insert item on position that would make `List` still ordered (with this method complexity is O(N) with any sort method its higer because many sort algorithms perform realy badly on almost sorted collection). Assuming that list is ordered when you add new item:

```
int index = 0;
foreach(var item in this)
{
    if(item.Order > newItem.Order)
    {
        this.Insert(index, newItem);
        break;
    }

    index++;
}
```